# Indication of current tab in Vim

Tags: vim, command-line

Disclaimer: I am new to Vim.

Is there a way to get better visual indication of current tab in Vim? Right now it looks like this for me:

[image: Current tab: r.html]

Comment: what do you mean by "tab"?

Comment: Tab as in tab in any other editor/browser. I have opened 3 files in 3 tabs in the picture, but I find it difficult to discern which tab is open now.

Comment: huh, never knew vim has tabs. Never used it before. I usually go with multiple terminals (which is equally good), or split screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 highligh groups for tabline highlighting.

```
TabLine     tab pages line, not active tab page label                           
TabLineFill tab pages line, where there are no labels                           
TabLineSel  tab pages line, active tab page label
```

with setting colors (or link other group) on the above groups, you can customize your tabline highlighting. Usually a colorscheme will predefine those groups for you.

E.g  https://github.com/sk1418/last256

has predefined:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is set by your colorscheme via `TabLineSel`. See `:h TabLineSel` and `:h setting-tabline`. Try

```
:hi TabLineSel ctermbg=131 guibg=#bd5353
```

to confirm.

Also, welcome to vim. Enjoy your stay. Tabs are useful for certain tasks, but many people forego them. You can change between various buffers without having them actively loaded in a window. For instance, if I type

```
vim 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

It will load up and display `1.txt`, but `2.txt` and `3.txt` are also loaded (they just aren't visible). You can see this with the `:ls` command. You can load up the other files using `:b`. For instance, `:b2` if I want to edit the second one. There are numerous plugins that also aid in improving this functionality. For instance, [vim-buffalo](https://github.com/Raimondi/vim-buffalo) allows you to start typing the partial name of a buffer. Various other file loading plugins allow this as well (e.g. Ctrl-p, FuzzyFinder, etc.)

Comment: I don't see the difference between tabs and buffers to the point of condemning former. Actually, tabs are far more expressive as they can contain layout (diff would be impossible in vim without tabs for instance). Apart from that, with few key mappings tab or buffer selection and usage is identical. Some plugins make this even more transparent (i.e. airline) to that matter that I initially didn't know what was tab, what was buffer.

Comment: Did you get that to work? I see no change while trying to use the command you suggested!

Comment: As you can see in `:h setting-tabline`, it is possible to modify which colorscheme groups are used in your `'tabline'` option. Your colorscheme likely sets your `'tabline'` option.

Comment: @majkinetor `:h window` and read just 3 lines of text under `Summary:`

Comment: @majkinetor you may have windows and tabs a little confused. Splits and diffs use windows, not tabs.

Comment: Yeah, but diffs are local to the current tab page. I did say it wrong, it would not be impossible, just impractical to use.